# Задача 'Неправильная считалка'

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Ребята во дворе решили поиграть в прятки. Чтобы выбрать ведущего, который будет искать, они решили воспользоваться считалкой. Считалка состоит из k слов и используется следующим образом.
> Все n ребят становятся в круг, и один из них, начиная с себя, по очереди указывает на ребят в порядке, в котором они стоят по кругу, называя слова считалки. Тот, на кого указывает считающий, называя последнее слово считалки, выбывает из круга. После этого считалка повторяется сначала, а счет начинается со следующего за выбывшим. Так продолжается до тех пор, пока в круге не останется один человек. Он то и будет ведущим.
> Но на этот раз ребята так увлеклись идеей предстоящей игры, что забывали выходить из круга после того, как считающий указывал на них, называя последнее слово считалки. В результате считающий снова указывал на них при следующих повторениях считалки.
> Ребята заметили это только тогда, когда после очередного повторения считалки считающий снова указал на последнем слове на участника, который уже должен был покинуть круг. Теперь их заинтересовал вопрос – а на скольких ребят в этот момент считающий все еще не указал, что они должны покинуть круг.

Помогите пожалуйста, вот мой код:

```py
a,b=map(int,input().split())
c=[0 for i in range(a)]
num=b%a+0-1
for j in range(1,a+2):
    if 2 in c:
        break
    if num >= a:
        num%=a
    c[num]+=1
    num+=j
print(c.count(0))
```

Но выдаёт неправильные ответы. Посмотрел в дебаггере, но и там не понял в чём ошибка.

**Пример входныx данных:**

6 14

**Пример выходных данных**

3

**Пример входныx данных:**

6 13

**Пример выходных данных**

0

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных и правильных и неправильных ответов.

Comment: Написал примеры данных

Answer (score 1):

Что вы добавляете к num в конце цикла? Не b ли там требуется?

А вообще задача эта может решаться без перебора *(кто знает, сколько там ребят - вдруг триллион?)* с использованием НОК

```
n - НОК(n,k)/k = n - n / НОД(n,k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял приведенный код с учетом нейминга переменных, но могу предложить вариант считалочки на бесконечном цикле

```
import itertools

children_count, words_count = (6, 14)
ext = []

for ix, c in enumerate(itertools.cycle([_ for _ in range(children_count)])):
    if not (ix + 1) % words_count:
        if c in ext:
            break
        ext.append(c)
print('Число ребят - {}'.format(children_count - len(ext)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```py
n, k = map(int, input().split())
step = k % n
gone = [0] * n
i = -1
count = n
while True:
    i = (i + step) % n
    if gone[i] == 1:
        break
    gone[i] = 1;
    count -= 1
print(count)
```